# Raster stack incorrecting plotting latitude and longitude coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates, r-raster

I've downloaded precipitation data from the TRMM (rainfall across the tropics) satellite as a netCDF file and have been trying to plot the data in R as a rasterstack. However, R insists on plotting the latitude and longitude axes incorrectly, such that longitude is plotted on the x-axis (as it should be) but uses the latitude coordinates, while latitude is on the y-axis, but uses the longitude coordinates. I've tried using both the `plot()` and `levelplot()` functions but neither seems to work. Can anyone help me correct this?

These are the characteristic of the stack:

```
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 1440, 186, 267840, 12  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : -23.25, 23.25, -180, 180  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : X2016.01.16, X2016.02.15, X2016.03.16, X2016.04.15, X2016.05.16, X2016.06.15, X2016.07.16, X2016.08.16, X2016.09.15, X2016.10.16, X2016.11.15, X2016.12.16 
Date        : 2016-01-16, 2016-02-15, 2016-03-16, 2016-04-15, 2016-05-16, 2016-06-15, 2016-07-16, 2016-08-16, 2016-09-15, 2016-10-16, 2016-11-15, 2016-12-16
```

In the following image you can see the current output. It should show rainfall over the tropics from -23 to 23 degrees latitude, and -180 to 180 degrees longitude.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's odd if the coordinates are switched prior to any processing. Maybe you want to asses the source you downloaded the data from and if there's maybe a better one.

Anyways, (in the meantime) the `raster` package can be of help for you .. specifically the transpose `t()` function. Here's an example:

```
# data before transpose
x <- getData('worldclim',var='tmean',res=10)
plot(x)
```

[image: Normal]

```
# data after transpose
y <- t(x)
plot(y)
```

[image: Transposed]

There are also a couple of other functions in `raster` which could be of interest for you: `flip` and `rotate`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response.  It does seem strange that the coordinates are messed up right out of the box, and I did try downloading a fresh set of data and the same problem occurred.  However, thanks to your input, I was able to rectify the problem through using the transpose() and flip() functions.  I had to transpose the data, then flip it along both the x and y dimensions as the image was 'mirrored'.  Here's the code I used in case anyone else encounters this problem with the TRMM data sets:

`a.t = t(test.rasterstack)
a.flipy = flip(a.t, direction = 2)
a.t.flipxy = flip(a.t.flipy, direction = 1)
levelplot(a.t.flipxy)`

Comment: Those datasets are rotated "by design". See also here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170137/converting-binary-trmm-to-geotiff-using-r/170173#170173

Comment: Thanks @LoBu, that's super helpful and I think I'll use the Rsenal package in the future